# Session not working in asp.net core 6.0 when tring to access it on the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I tried working with session on ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC but could not make it work as shown in the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I added the session middleware on program.cs.

```
builder.Services.AddSession();
app.UseSession();
```

On the controller I am storing current datetime on session:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("CurrentDateTime", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Till now everything is fine.

But problem is I am getting error when on the view I am trying to access it like this:

```
@HttpContext.Session.GetString("CurrentDateTime")
```

The error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
> (active)  CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static
> field, method, or property
> 'HttpContext.Session' UnderstandingControllersViews   E:\Yogesh\SEO\Yogihosting\3\UnderstandingControllersViews\UnderstandingControllersViews\Views\Example\SessionExample.cshtml 2

How to make it work can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` implementation to your `View` and use it to get the `Session` object as required:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{
    //Get object from session
    var mySessionObject= HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("CurrentDateTime");
 }

<h1>@mySessionObject</h1>
```